# ReportViewer with multiple dataset running in localreport

Tags: c#, reportbuilder3.0

I need excecute a ReportViewer in local processing mode with two data sources, but I have a problem with the second.

I desing the report with report builder 3 and it run fine there (both dataset fill their respectives tables).

But when I render the report in C#, the second dataset is empty, this is the code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = nodoDataSet[0].FirstChild.InnerText.ToString().Replace("@Id", id.ToString());
System.Data.DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
cmd2.Connection = con;
cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd2.CommandText = nodoDataSet[1].FirstChild.InnerText.ToString().Replace("@Id", id.ToString());
System.Data.DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
dt2.Load(cmd2.ExecuteReader());

con.Close();

ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();
viewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = urlReporte;
viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource() { Name = "Consulta", Value = dt });
viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource() { Name = "Consulta2", Value = dt2 });
viewer.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;

List<ReportParameter>() parametros = new List<ReportParameter>(){
    new ReportParameter("Id",id.ToString()),
};
viewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(parametros);
pdf.Add(viewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF"));
```

I open the xml to read the SQL query and replace the parameters, run the query in the server and load a DataTable, I do this for each query, both commands get data.

Then just add the two data sources to the report and render it as PDF.

The problem is that in the code, the second table remains empty:

Good: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOmcH.png

Bad: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp0fI.png

So, the question is, why?

Thanks!

Comment: Put a breakpoint after `dt2.Load`. Does dt2 have data?

Comment: Hello Pikoh, yes, dt2 gets 3 records from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution!

I just check the "User single transaction when processing the queries" option in the Data Source Properties dialog and it works!